# Neo4J - SpringData - @query using compound query

Tags: neo4j, spring-data, spring-data-neo4j

I'm kind of new to Neo4J: I've built an application that uses Neo4j using SpringData.
I have a @NodeEntity that contains 'name' and 'year' properties and as a search by name and year is commonly used, I defined a compound index on these two fields:

```
@Getter
@Setter
@NoArgsConstructor
@ToString(of = { "name", "year" })
public abstract class BaseContent<D extends BaseContentDTO> extends BaseEntity {

    @Indexed(indexName = "search_content")
    protected String name;

    @Indexed(indexName = "search_content")
    protected Integer year;
}
```

I'm trying to query content by name and year, using this compound index.
This query works from the Neo4j web-admin, but it doesn't when I try to run it with SpringData.

This is my query in SpringData:

```
@Query("start movie=node:search_content(\"name={name} AND year={year}\") return movie;")
public T findByNameAndYear(@Param("name") String name, @Param("year") Integer year);
```

The error I'm getting:

```
org.apache.cxf.interceptor.Fault: null at
BadInputException
```

I don't understand what I'm doing wrong.
I've tried different variations, like using {0} and {1} instead of param names, but this doesn't help either.

By the way, this is the Cypher query, works well in the web-admin:

```
start movie=node:search_content('name:Salt AND year:2010') return movie.name, movie.year;
```

And if I use in the @query ':' instead of '=' like this:

```
@Query("start movie=node:search_content(\"name:{name} AND year:{year}\") return movie;")
```

I get this error:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: org.apache.cxf.interceptor.Fault: org.apache.lucene.queryParser.ParseException: Cannot parse 'name:{name} AND year:{year}': Encountered " "}" "} "" at line 1, column 10.
Was expecting one of:
    "TO" ...
    <RANGEEX_QUOTED> ...
    <RANGEEX_GOOP> ...
     at
```

I really appreciate your assistance,

Carmel

Comment: have you tried with this : 
`@Query("start movie=node:search_content(name={name} AND year={year}) return movie.name, movie.year)` ? I mean without any `\"`

Comment: I have. This is the exception it throws: java.lang.RuntimeException: org.apache.cxf.interceptor.Fault: Unclosed parenthesis
"start movie=node:search_content(name={name} AND year={year}) return movie;"
                                             ^ at
SyntaxException

Comment: I actually have doubt on query structure. Why don't you take out your actual query look up out side the `()`. I mean inside parenthesis you need to mention explicitly some value over which cypher will look out.  `@Query("start movie=node:search_content(name='Matrix') WHERE movie.year={year} return movie)` this will search all the nodes based on index `search_content` and one property as `name='Matrix'`. I am not sure about this, but just give it a try.

Comment: basically `()` is applied in more broader way over the index given. in above comment, I have mentioned it explicitly name='Matrix' but it could have other value like className='org.abc.Movie' or something like that.

Comment: The last one works. Thanks (though I still don't realize why a cipher query that works on the admin doesn't work on the SpringData). Thanks again :)

Comment: you are welcome. may be query is being analyzed in different way, still learning it. :)

Comment: Parameters inside of query strings are not substituted, so you have to construct the query on the outside. Also you should change your `@Indexed(indexName = "search_content", numeric=false)
    protected Integer year;` To allow cypher to use that index too. Unfortunately there are some issues with numeric indexes, lucene-query-strings, so you have to disable numeric indexing for that field.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to take out your actual query look up out side the (). I mean inside parenthesis you need to mention explicitly some value over which cypher will look out.
`@Query("start movie=node:search_content(name='Matrix') WHERE movie.year={year} return movie)`
This will search all the nodes based on index **search_content** and one property as `name='Matrix'`, but it could have other value like `className='org.abc.Movie'` or something like that.